# Is it possible to specify a specific "after feature" hook for each behave feature?

Tags: python, cucumber, bdd, python-behave

I know, in [behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io), it is possible to use an `environment.py` to specify `before_feature()` and `after_feature()` functions to execute setup and teardown code before or after **every** feature.

However, is there a way to specify a custom after feature function that is only executed for the **specific** feature?

In my searching online, I found a few pages discussing possible ways to do this using cucumber-jvm, but nothing on doing this with behave:

- [Getting @BeforeAll and @AfterAll behaviour with Cucumber JVM and JUnit](https://www.metamorphant.de/blog/posts/2020-03-10-beforeall-afterall-cucumber-jvm-junit/)
- [Add @BeforeAll and @AfterAll hooks cucumber-jvm GitHub issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/515)
- [cucumber-jvm global hook workarounds](https://automationpanda.com/2017/03/03/cucumber-jvm-global-hook-workarounds/)

To give an example, I'd like to do something similar to this:

```
Feature: My feature

AfterFeature:
  Then Database is reset

# Scenarios
```

One thing I thought of is maybe the `context` can be looked at in the "global" `after_feature()` function, and then custom code can be run if the feature's name matches the desired name. For example, something like:

```py
# In environment.py

def after_all(context):
    if context.feature.name == 'feature_with_custom_teardown.feature':
        # Do custom teardown

    # Do regular teardown
```

However, when I tried inspecting the `context` in my `after_all()` function, for some reason the feature was `None` - but maybe this just means I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this:

In `environment.py` you might add something like:

```
def after_feature(context, feature):
    if feature.name == 'My feature':
        # Do custom teardown
```

You could also work with feature tags instead of name, which is more practical if you know there will be more than one feature requiring the setup/teardown. So if your feature file is tagged something like

```
@database-reset-required
Feature: My feature

# Scenarios here
```

, then, for the teardown part, in `environment.py` you could have:

```
def after_feature(context, feature):
    if 'database-reset-required' in feature.tags:
        # Do custom teardown
```

If you go for the `feature.name` approach and not `feature.tags` note that you need to use the *name* defined within the feature file i.e. this part `Feature: *My feature*`, NOT the filename.